# Confusion with referencing items in a array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding how this code outputs 10. I understand that p is the address of the first element in the pointer array, meaning  p+1 is the address of the second element of the list. Meaning *(p+1) is the address of the first element of array n. Consequently * (*(p+1) + 1) evaluated to the 2nd element of array n. However, I'm getting confused as to how the below code prints the value 10, meaning the first element of array r. Help is greatly appreciated.

```
int m[4]={-2,3,6,8,9}, n[4]={7,6,4,3}, r[4]={10,-3,5};
int *p[3]={m,n,r};
printf("%d", *((p+1)[1]));
```

Comment: A nit on the code but m[4] has 5 values.  Compile with option -Werror to find issues like this.

Comment: `(p+1)[1]` is `*((p+1)+1)`, not `*(p+1)+1`

Answer (score 1):

Starting at `p`:

- `p`: `{m, n, r}`
- `p+1`: `{n, r}`
- `(p+1)`: `{n, r}`
- `(p+1)[1]`: `r`
- `((p+1)[1])`: `r`
- `((p+1)[1])`: `{10, -3, 5}`
- `*((p+1)[1])`: `10`

Note that `(p+1)[1]` means `*((p+1)+1)`, not `(*(p+1))+1`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of pointers, so *p* is the pointer to -2 (beginning of the *m* array) and *p+1* is the pointer to 7 (beginning of the *n* array).

So *p* is the pointer to the beginning of the array that contains 3 pointers and *p+1* is the pointer to the beginning of an array that contains 2 pointers and when you write *(p+1)[1]* you get the same result as *p[2]*.

```
*p[2] == *(p+1)[1] == *(p+2)
```